# Making Command-key the Emacs Meta-key under VMware/Windows

Tags: windows, macos, emacs, vmware

I can configure emacs under OS X so that the key nearest the space bar (the key labeled Command ⌘) is my Meta key by running

```
(setq mac-command-key-is-meta t)
```

How can I configure the same key to be the emacs Meta-key when I run emacs under Windows and Windows is itself running in VMware Fusion? For some reason even if I run the above line on Windows-VMware, my Meta key remains the Option key.

Comment: It could be to do with how VMware passes the keystroke through to the virtual machine, rather than emacs.

Answer (score 0):

I use [keyremap4macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) for a similar situation (Remotedesktop to windows PC). You can set remaps which are only valid in specific applications.